# How add lines in a text to an append request on API Google spreadsheet without destroy my quota

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm not an expert programmer and I extract some data to a text file, and now I want to import it to a Google spreadsheet. I can do this and it works till quota limits. How can I add all the lines to a single request?

```
 insert_data_option = 'OVERWRITE'  

        
        with open(r"juntos.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as inputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                string = line.rstrip(" \n")
                value_range_body = {
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "range": "A:B",
  "values": [
    [
      string
    ]
  ]
}

                request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
                response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to append the values to Spreadsheet using one API call of Sheets API.

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
insert_data_option = 'OVERWRITE'

data = []
with open("juntos.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        string = line.rstrip(" \n")
        data.append([string])
value_input_option = "USER_ENTERED"
value_range_body = {"values": data}
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="A:B", valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()
```

- In this case, the values are appended to the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet by one API call.

#### Note:

- In your situation, in order to retrieve `data`, the following script might be able to be also used.

  ```
    data = []
    with open("juntos.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read().split("\n")
    data = [[e.rstrip(" \n")] for e in data]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)